# Google Chrome printing from a tablet stylesheet

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using a pretty standard print stylesheet for my webpage, and it works perfect in all browsers except for Google Chrome. Whenever I print the page in Chrome it both previews it and prints it using my tablet stylesheet. When printed from another browser it prints using the standard stylesheet.
All of my other webpages print fine in chrome, but this one webpage is giving me trouble. Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

The following is my print.css file.

```
body {line-height:1.5;font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000;background:none;font-size:10pt;/*margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;*/}
#page-wrapper.container {background:none;
min-width:960px;
max-width:960px;
width:100%}
hr {background:#ccc;color:#ccc;width:100%;height:2px;margin:2em 0;padding:0;border:none;}
hr.space {background:#fff;color:#fff;visibility:hidden;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;}
code {font:.9em "Courier New", Monaco, Courier, monospace;}
a img {border:none;}
p img.top {margin-top:0;}
blockquote {margin:1.5em;padding:1em;font-style:italic;font-size:.9em;}
.small {font-size:.9em;}
.large {font-size:1.1em;}
.quiet {color:#999;}
.hide {display:none;}
a:link, a:visited {background:transparent;font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please include the code snippet of where the CSS gets included into the page? if `media="print"` is set on the `link tag` for our tablet stylesheet, then that's what the printer will use. Without some code, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: I edited in my print.css file. I am creating this website using drupal from a premade theme so I have not created this file. I have already searched for links to the stylesheet and asked around on drupal forums and the only thing that links the print.css stylesheet to printing is the following line 
`stylesheets[print][]      = css//blueprint/print.css`
in a .info file.